# $a,b,c ∈ \mathbb R^+$ and $a+b=1$ then find max value of $a^4b + ab^4$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

$a,b,c ∈ \mathbb R^+$ and $a+b=1$ then find max value of $a^4b + ab^4$

So through *AM-GM*, I found :
$$\frac{a+b}{2}\ge\sqrt{ab}\implies ab \le 1$$

Now I have, $$ab(a^3+b^3)\le\frac{1}{4}(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)$$
$$ab(a^3+b^3) \le \left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{4}-\frac{ab}{4}\right)$$

To me, it looks like I’m halfway there and just need to find something about $a^2 + b^2$ but haven’t found anything. Any type of help is welcomed.

Comment: I believe your statement $ab \le 1$ should be $ab \le \frac{1}{4}$ instead.

Comment: Why $a,b,c ∈ \Bbb R^+$? There is no $c$ in your inequality.

Comment: Determining the extrema of $f(a) = a^4(1-a) + a(1-a)^4$ on $[0, 1]$ via the derivative should be straightforward calculation.

Comment: I don't think you should apply AM-GM immediately.  The maxima occurs at $a,b=\frac12\pm\frac1{2\sqrt3}$ which is different from the maxima of $ab$ ($a=b=\frac12$) from AM-GM, so that step is mostly useless for computing the maxima.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $a,b ∈ R^+$ and $a+b=1$,

$$a^4b +ab^4=ab(a^3 + b^3) =$$
$$= ab[(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)]=ab(1-3ab)=$$
$$=ab - 3a^2b^2=-3(a^2b^2-\frac{ab}{3})=$$
$$-3(a^2b^2-\frac{ab}{3}+\frac{1}{36})+\frac{1}{12}=$$
$$=-3(ab-\frac{1}{6})^2 +\frac{1}{12} \leq \frac{1}{12}$$